# Finding $u$ and $v$ in Jacobian substitutions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, transformation

I've used Jacobians before in multivariable calculus to simplify integrals, but I'm lost when I need to find the substitutions myself.  Today on the quiz, there was the problem

$\int\int_{R} xy dxdy$ given a region $R$ bounded by

$y=\frac{2x+5}{3}$

$y=\frac{2x+2}{3}$

$y=\frac{-5-5x}{2}$

$y=\frac{-3-5x}{2}$

I know how to calculate the Jacobian if I know the substitutions, but I'm lost on how to calculate the substitutions.  I've tried the following:

$u = xy, v=1$

I get a feeling, that given the limits, that both $u$ and $v$ will be linearly related to $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Typically you choose the transformation so that the boundaries of the region are straight lines of constant $u$ and $v$ in the new coordinates.

Comment: That's what I thought, but how would I do that?  Do I arbitrarily say $u=1$ and go from there?

Comment: Not really.  First things first, though: you repeated an equation, so it's hard to tell what your region should be.

Comment: @Muphrid thanks for catching that.  I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your bounding equations to solve for constant factors like so:

$$2x - 3y = -5 \\2x - 3y = -2 \\ 5x + 2y = -5 \\ 5x + 2y = -3$$

One way to look at this is that you're solving for constants (on the left), so to speak.

How can we think about this in general terms?  Well, imagine a rectangular region on a Cartesian coordinate system, from $(0,0)$ to $(a,0)$ to $(a,b)$ to $(0,b)$.  This is bounded by four curves: $x = 0$, $x=a$, $y=0$, and $y=b$.  The region is bounded by four curves of constant coordinates, two for each coordinate.

I think you should now be able to see here how you can define the new coordinates so that the region's boundaries can be expressed just as simply.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was wondering about how I would transform the boundaries, but this method seems to be cleanest.